# Insert changeset in liquibase does not work

Tags: liquibase

I started integrating liquibase script in my spring boot code. Right now I only have 2 changeSets and my liquibase script is as follows:

```
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:
    id: liquibase-create-1
    author: liquibase
    preConditions:
      onFail: MARK_RAN
      not:
        sequenceExists:
          sequenceName: APP_USER_SEQ
    changes:
    - createSequence:
         sequenceName: APP_USER_SEQ
         startValue: 1
         minValue: 1
         incrementBy: 1

- changeSet: 
    id: liquibase-create-2
    author: liquibase
    preCondition:
      onFail: MARK_RAN
      not:
        tableExists: 
          tableName: APP_USER
    changes:
    -createTable: 
        tableName: APP_USER
        columns:
          - column:
            name: ID
            constraints:
              primaryKey: true
              nullable: false
              primaryKeyName: APP_USER_PK
            type: INTEGER
          - column:
            name: VERSION
            type: INTEGER
          - column:
            name: USER_ID
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
            name: USER_TYPE
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            type: INTEGER
          - column:
            name: PASSWORD
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
            name: FIRST_NM
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
            name: LAST_NM
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
            name: DISPLAY_NM
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
            name: DEPARTMENT
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
            name: EMAIL_ID
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
            name: PHONE_NO
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
            name: LOCATION
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            type: VARCHAR(50)
```

While the application boots up in a smoothly, I come across a strange behavior that only the sequence is created successfully but there is no table app_user in my schema.
Also logs support my observation:

```
2020-09-09 23:09:57.992  INFO 6680 --- [           main] liquibase    
: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml:
db/changelog/changes/db.changelog-create-v1.yml::liquibase-create-1::liquibase:
Sequence APP_USER_SEQ created 2020-09-09 23:09:57.993  INFO 6680 --- [
main] liquibase                                :
classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml:
db/changelog/changes/db.changelog-create-v1.yml::liquibase-create-1::liquibase:
ChangeSet
db/changelog/changes/db.changelog-create-v1.yml::liquibase-create-1::liquibase
ran successfully in 36ms 2020-09-09 23:09:58.020  INFO 6680 --- [     
main] liquibase                                :
classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml:
db/changelog/changes/db.changelog-create-v1.yml::liquibase-create-2::liquibase:
ChangeSet
db/changelog/changes/db.changelog-create-v1.yml::liquibase-create-2::liquibase
ran successfully in 0ms
```

To say it precisly, it says **liquibase-create-2 ran successfully in 0ms**

Can anyone help with what the problem might be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an indentation issue. Worked fine with:

```
- changeSet: 
    id: liquibase-create-2
    author: liquibase
    preCondition:
      onFail: MARK_RAN
      not:
        tableExists: 
          tableName: APP_USER
    changes:
    - createTable: 
        tableName: APP_USER
        columns:
          - column:
              name: ID
              constraints:
                primaryKey: true
                nullable: false
                primaryKeyName: APP_USER_PK
              type: INTEGER
          - column:
              name: VERSION
              type: INTEGER
          - column:
              name: USER_ID
              constraints:
                nullable: false
              type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
              name: USER_TYPE
              constraints:
                nullable: false
              type: INTEGER
          - column:
              name: PASSWORD
              constraints:
                nullable: false
              type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
              name: FIRST_NM
              constraints:
                nullable: false
              type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
              name: LAST_NM
              constraints:
                nullable: false
              type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
              name: DISPLAY_NM
              constraints:
                nullable: false
              type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
              name: DEPARTMENT
              constraints:
                nullable: false
              type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
              name: EMAIL_ID
              constraints:
                nullable: false
              type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
              name: PHONE_NO
              constraints:
                nullable: false
              type: VARCHAR(50)
          - column:
              name: LOCATION
              constraints:
                nullable: false
              type: VARCHAR(50)
```